# Magento 2 : How to configure cookie free domain?

Tags: magento2, cookie, system-configuration

In GTMetrix, I checked "Use cookie-free domains" result is 0 and also checked that there are Magento 2 default provide this configuration.

How to setup that and upgrade maximum "Use cookie-free domains" score ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you manage to set it up?